# Название UI элемента

Tags: ui

Как называются такие выезжающие элементы? [открытое состояние](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVQHh.png)[image: закрытое состояние]

Comment: Он называется [Accordion](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0))

Comment: Спасибо! Понял.